# Tetris getting slower every time I complete a row (Python, Turtle)

Tags: python, performance, turtle-graphics, tetris

I am trying to make Tetris in python with turtle library and I have problem I don't know how to fix. At the beginning game work nice, but every time you complete row it slows down and after 5-6 times it becomes unplayable. Here is video of gameplay (I didn't finish it yet):
https://youtu.be/f8cENc-fP7E

Here is whole code:
https://pastebin.com/kS8yGJQ7

but problem is probably in function check:

```
def check():
    global pen2, pen3
    
    for i in range(len(blocks2)):
        blocksfordelete = []
        k = 0
        
        for j in range(len(blocks2)):
            if blocks2[i][1] == blocks2[j][1]:
                blocksfordelete.append(blocks2[j])
                k += 1
        
        if k == 13:
            for m in range(len(blocksfordelete)):
                pen4 = turtle.Turtle("square")
                pen4.shapesize(squaresize / 20)
                pen4.penup()
                pen4.color("white")
                pen4.goto(blocksfordelete[m][0], blocksfordelete[m][1])
                pen4.stamp()
                
            for n in blocksfordelete:
                if n in blocks2:
                    blocks2.remove(n)
 
            for x in blocks2:
                if x[1] > blocksfordelete[0][1]:
                    pen5 = turtle.Turtle("square")
                    pen5.shapesize(squaresize / 20)
                    pen5.penup()
                    pen5.color("white")
                    pen5.goto(x[0], x[1])
                    pen5.stamp()
 
                    pen6 = turtle.Turtle("square")
                    pen6.shapesize(squaresize / 20)
                    pen6.penup()
                    x[1] -= squaresize
                    pen6.color("black")
                    pen6.goto(x[0], x[1])
                    pen6.stamp()
 
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of performance issues with your code.  First, you dynamically create turtles over and over again.  Though not clear from the documentation, turtles are essentially global entities that never go away unless you reset the screen or quit out of turtle.  Create just the ones you need and reuse them

Second, you use stamping and clearing to display the falling turtle as it moves sideways and down.  We can simply use a *live* turtle for this purpose and leave the stamping code for the turtle pile at the bottom of the screen.  Below is your code reworked as described above along with lots of tweaks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SQUARE_SIZE = 30
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

WIDTH = 400 + SQUARE_SIZE/2
HEIGHT = 600 + SQUARE_SIZE/2

delay = 300
blocks1 = []
blocks2 = []

def start():
    blocks1.append([0, HEIGHT/2 + SQUARE_SIZE/2])
    pen_falling.showturtle()
    update()

def update():
    blocks1[0][1] -= 30

    if blocks1[0] in blocks2:
        blocks1[0][1] += SQUARE_SIZE
        pen_black.goto(blocks1[0])
        pen_black.stamp()
        blocks2.append(blocks1.pop(0))
        check()
        start()
    elif blocks1[0][1] == -HEIGHT/2 + 30:
        pen_black.goto(blocks1[0])
        pen_black.stamp()
        blocks2.append(blocks1.pop(0))
        check()
        start()
    else:
        pen_falling.goto(blocks1[0])
        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(update, delay)

def down1():
    global delay
    delay = 50

def down2():
    global delay
    delay = 300

def right():
    if blocks1[0][0] < WIDTH/2 - SQUARE_SIZE:
        blocks1[0][0] += SQUARE_SIZE

        if blocks1[0] not in blocks2:
            pen_falling.goto(blocks1[0])
        else:
            blocks1[0][0] -= SQUARE_SIZE

def left():
    if blocks1[0][0] > -WIDTH/2 + SQUARE_SIZE:
        blocks1[0][0] -= SQUARE_SIZE

        if blocks1[0] not in blocks2:
            pen_falling.goto(blocks1[0])
        else:
            blocks1[0][0] += SQUARE_SIZE

def check():
    for i in range(len(blocks2)):
        blocksfordelete = []
        k = 0

        for block in blocks2:
            if blocks2[i][1] == block[1]:
                blocksfordelete.append(block)
                k += 1

        if k == 13:
            for block in blocksfordelete:
                pen_white.goto(block)
                pen_white.stamp()

            for block in blocksfordelete:
                if block in blocks2:
                    blocks2.remove(block)

            for block in blocks2:
                if block[1] > blocksfordelete[0][1]:
                    pen_white.goto(block)
                    pen_white.stamp()

                    block[1] -= SQUARE_SIZE

                    pen_black.goto(block)
                    pen_black.stamp()

            break

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.title("Tetris")
screen.tracer(False)

pen_falling = Turtle('square')
pen_falling.hideturtle()
pen_falling.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
pen_falling.penup()
pen_falling.color('black')

pen_black = Turtle('square')
pen_black.hideturtle()
pen_black.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
pen_black.penup()
pen_black.color('black')

pen_white = Turtle('square')
pen_white.hideturtle()
pen_white.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
pen_white.penup()
pen_white.color('white')

screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(down1, 'Down')
screen.onkeyrelease(down2, 'Down')
screen.onkey(screen.bye, 'Escape')

screen.listen()

start()

screen.mainloop()
```

If you still have a performance issue, let me know and I'll look deeper.

For more performance, consider *managing* your stamps rather than overwriting them.  Individual stamps can be removed if you keep track of their *stamp id* as returned by the `stamp()` method.

Nice use of `onkeypress()` vs. `onkeyrelease()` for the down arrow key!